# half goat and half sheep

Tags: indefinite-article, zero-article, quantifiers

> **a.)** This animal is *half* goat and *half* sheep.

> **b.)** This animal looks *half* like a goat and *half* like a sheep.

In sentence **a**, half does not need to be followed by an indefinite article, does it? But why? In sentence **b**, "goat' and "sheep" each have an indefinite article. Why the difference? How do you analyze **a**?

Answer (score 1):

> This animal **is** half goat and half sheep

When you use "**is**", this means that the animal in question bears some *permanent traits* that will either be considered a sheep or a goat based on **different** aspects. Maybe it's a goat-sheep offspring: it has both the genes from a goat and a sheep; or maybe one side of it is a goat, the other side is a sheep, kind of like what you'd get if you chop both a sheep and a goat in half and join each half together; etc.

**Sidenote**: when phrased this way, this sentence is really vague and it's very hard to pinpoint the exact meaning the speaker is getting at.

> This animal **is** half *a* goat and half *a* sheep

When phrased this way, personally, I'd consider it to **lean more to the latter meaning** (*one side of it is a goat, the other side is a sheep, kind of like what you'd get if you chop both a sheep and a goat in half and join each half together*); but it's still quite similar to the above sentence.

> This animal looks half like (a) goat and half like (a) sheep.

In this sentence, I feel like the articles can be ommitted without significant change in meaning. To me, "a" just feels like a **meaningless filler** without conveying much meaning in numbers.

Unfortunately, I have no other sources other than my ear.

Comment: In the "like" sentences, the indefinite article doesn't alter the meaning, but it is syntactically needed. "This animal looks like goat" -> there's a bit of non-parallelism because you're comparing a singular animal to... what? "These animals look like goats" -> no article needed

Comment: @AndyBonner I agree, I actually intended to answer the exact same way you did. But after consideration, I felt like in everyday English, omitting the article wouldn't sound too bizzare.